# Is it necessary to assign null to a local variable at the end of a method, such as List<Student> in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have define a method to deal with a scheduled task every hour.In my method I have a local variable,Is it necessary to assign null to a local variable at the end of a method? The IDEA tell me:

> stuentList=null;

> The value null assigned to 'stuentList' is never used, remove redundant assignment.

So I think it is not necessary, is that right?

```
private void dealWithStudent(){
  List<Student> stuentList=new  new ArrayList<Student>();
  //query condition and assign to stuentList
  //use stuentList to insert to db
  stuentList=null;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not necessary.

Comment: It literally says "The value null assigned to 'stuentList' is never used, remove redundant assignment." - that is, it serves no purpose, so remove it.

Answer (score 1):

No, once you leave the method the variables defined within that block are descoped and marked for garbage collection.